# Speed up sending responses to websocket client with netty

Tags: websocket, netty

We have a web app making use of websocket with netty.  We are trying to push through a large stream of data and noticing that once we hit about 300-400 responses a second, the channel begins to get marked as NOT_WRITABLE and we are unable to send some of the responses.

It seems as though netty is waiting for an ack on the socket.  Is there any way to disable that, or any way to speed it up to be able to handle more?  The javascript implementation in chrome is pretty bare-bones and it doesn't seem like there's much we can do to increase performance from that side.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your write faster then the data can be "send out" to the client. You can try to increase the write watermark. See [1].

Als you may want to experiment with some TCP opts like "tcpNoDelay" and "sendBufferSize". See [2]

[1] http://static.netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/nio/NioChannelConfig.html#setWriteBufferHighWaterMark(int)
[2] http://static.netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/SocketChannelConfig.html

Comment: Thanks Norman, we have already adjusted sendBufferSize and set tcpNoDelay.  Interestingly, there was a negative effect on performance setting tcpNoDelay and we changed it back to false.  The only remaining thing that I think could speed things up would be to remove the wait for ack.